# Image looks different in chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, image, browser

This is(https://gorgelogic.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?ownerId=ashah&avatarId=11101) a image url. I am getting different view in chrome and firefox. And when download this image using Webclient in C# getting same image as seen in Firefox.

Actually uploaded image is same as Chrome one.

SO question is:
I want to show image on my website page. I have attached image link here. If you check that link in Firefox and chrome, you see two different images. Image seems in Chrome is actual uploaded image. Problem is when I download this image using code I m getting different image which you can see in Firefox. So in short I am getting wrong image.

Comment: Hi, what's your question exactly?

Comment: I want to show image on my website page. I have attached image link here. If you check that link in Firefox and chrome, you see two different images. Image seems in Chrome is actual uploaded image. Problem is when I download this image using code I m getting different image which you can see in Firefox. So in short I am getting wrong image.

Comment: I can't spot any significant difference in the images.

Comment: In Chrome: http://snag.gy/HtIi8.jpg   In Firefox: http://snag.gy/snba7.jpg  Both image url is same

Comment: Have you cleared the browser's cache (usually ctrl+F5), because here, in chrome and in firefox the look the same: blue background, white-like silhouette.

Comment: This is hard to get consistently right as no all browser will treat image alike, be it that they do contain a __color profile__, which some version of some browsers ignore or that they don't and some browsers may use some __default color profile__.. Adding one is still your best bet..

Comment: yes cleared cache. And uploaded different image and checked for each. Chrome is showing correct. But in downloading getting wrong which seem in Firefox. Both screen shot is attached.

Comment: @TaW OK.. But when I download using C# webclient I am getting different image. So how can I resolve it?

Comment: Do you mean automatically, without looking at the images? Are those downloads coming from different sources?

Comment: See See I have uploaded image at https://gorgelogic.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?ownerId=ashah&avatarId=11101 .Uploaded image is look like http://snag.gy/HtIi8.jpg but when I download this imag eusing C# WebClient class, I am geeting image like http://snag.gy/snba7.jpg this. And that is wrong image. I have not uploaded this image.

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry, but after looking at the two links in the comment I'm confused. This doesn't seem to be about color profiles after all, but about two totally different images! Which means that the server makes the distinction what to serve to each browser.. Weird, I wonder why..? One looks like a default for no-real avatar or for image-not-found..

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely a cache/temp files issue. I am getting the same picture with Firefox as w ith Chrome.

Reload the link in Chrome by hitting Ctrl+F5, this will force a complete refresh/reload from Server.

Comment: No this is not a cache issue. I have done that but getting same as earlier. If you read you will find problem is getting wrong image in downloading which seems in Firefox.

Comment: And as I said, I am getting the same image no matter what browser. Hell I even tried IE. This means it is not dependent on the client browser but must be a problem connected to you personally.